# Why are my select tags not displaying correctly in Firefox and IE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, firefox

Using Jquery, I would like to be able to dynamically populate on focus a select field that may already have a value. After it's been populated, I would like to set the select tag's value to the prior value if it exists as an option in the new field. I can accomplish this in Chrome, but in Internet Explorer and Firefox I experience differing, unexpected behavior. A description of the problem, some sample code, and a link to a JSFiddle with the sample code follow.

In Firefox, if the user only tabs into the field, it works as intended. If the user clicks the field, the contents and the value update as intended, but if the field loses focus before the user clicks an item in the dropdown list (which the user is wont to do since the previous value could still be highlighted), the value will then update to the topmost option in the select tag.

In IE when the user clicks the field, the javascript fires and I believe updates the DOM, but the result of the change will not be displayed until the field loses focus. Thus the dropdown displayed to the user is of the now removed options, not the newly appended ones. If the select tag loses focus without the user selecting an option, it works as intended (but if the user clicks it again, the font in the dropdown mysteriously changes to serif. Bonus points if you can tell me why that happens).

I was wondering if there might be something wrong with my code or if my issues are caused by bugs (or features) in the browsers.

```
<p>
    <select>
        <option value='aaa'>aaa</option>
        <option value='bbb' selected="selected">bbb</option>
    </select>
</p>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var newOpts = "<option value='ccc'>ccc</option><option value='ddd'>ddd</option><option value='bbb'>bbb</option>";

        var $select = $("select");
        var selectedOpt = $select.val();

        $select.focus(function() {
            $select
                .empty()
                .append(newOpts)
                .val(selectedOpt);
        });
    });
</script>
```

[I have the above in JSFiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/f99cbqxw/)

A similar JSFiddle example [exists here](http://jsfiddle.net/NAHXP/417/), explicitly displaying an appended option each time the select tag is clicked.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Event handling for the `select` element can vary greatly from browser to browser.

A somewhat hacky solution, which seems to work consistently cross-browser, is to simulate opening the select element on focus, then closing it on blur:

```js
var newOpts = "<option value='ccc'>ccc</option><option value='ddd'>ddd</option><option value='bbb'>bbb</option>";

var $select = $("select");
var selectedOpt = $select.val();

$select.focus(function() {
  if(!$(this)[0].size) {
    $(this)
      .empty()
      .append(newOpts)
      .val(selectedOpt)
    $(this)[0].size= $(this)[0].options.length;
    
  }
});

$select.on('change blur', function() {
  $(this)[0].size= 0;
});
```

```css
select {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span style="position:relative;width:4em;float:left">
  &nbsp;
  <select>
    <option value='aaa'>aaa</option>
    <option value='bbb' selected="selected">bbb</option>
  </select>
</span>
<input>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Not to nitpick , but would you know how I could maintain the select tag's default behavior of presenting a dropdown list as a popover instead of resizing the entire tag as this does?

Comment: Not nitpicking at all!  I've updated the code, now putting an absolute-positioned `select` inside a relative-positioned `span`.  I had to give the span a width, which only worked if I added non-positioned content to it (in this case, a non-breaking space).  A real kludge-and-a-hack, but certainly better than causing a reflow of *all* content.

Comment: One last question. Normally after a select tag is opened, clicking an option or highlighting one with the arrow keys and hitting enter closes the tag. Can I preserve that functionality here? I tried adding handlers to the focusin and click events that check the size of the tag and if it's not zero calls blur, but I can't get it to work either way. [Here's my fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/bzfr2up3/3/) Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: Sure.  I've updated the code to close the select during a `change` event as well as a `blur` event.

Answer (score 0):

.val() doesn't work well with selects.  Instead, get the text of the selected option like this:

```
var Selected = $("select option:selected").text();
```

Then, once you've replaced the select's options, do this:

```
$("select option").each(function() {
    if ($(this).text() == Selected) {
        $(this).attr("selected", "selected");
    }
});
```